# I can install via gacutil, but not uninstall the same dll

Tags: c#, gac, gacutil

I have installed a DLL using the gacutil.

```
gacutil.exe /i SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.Exceptions.dll
```

Using the gacutil /l shows that it is indeed installed.

```
SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.Exceptions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=925c8734ae397609, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

Then I wanted to uninstall it.

```
gacutil.exe /u SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.Exceptions.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

No assemblies found matching: SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.Exceptions.dll
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 0
Number of failures = 0
```

Why doesn't this work? How do I uninstall it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Installing an assembly requires the *path name* of the DLL.  Uninstalling requires the *display name* of the assembly.  They don't have to resemble each other.  Review the `Assembly.FullName` property.  `gacutil.exe /l` (ell as in list) gets you a list of display names.

Answer (score 9):

Nevermind.

```
gacutil.exe /u SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.Exceptions
```

Did the job. Also navigating to C:\WINDOWS\assembly, right-click on it and then choose uninstall would do it. I figured it out by looking at its properties and the name was without the dll extension.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little safer if you have multiple assemblies with the same display name in the GAC

```
gactutil.exe /u myDll,Version=1.1.0.0,Culture=en,PublicKeyToken=874e23ab874e23ab
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here while finding answer but did not get fully .

what you actually need to do is to use double quotes  "Assemblyname" surrounding complete assembly name i.e

"YOURDLLNAME, Version=6.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Complete process , navigate to this path using command prompt : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

and run query : gactuil.exe /u "YOURDLLNAME, Version=6.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Note, don't specify .dll on the dll name.

Comment: This method also works when you want to uninstall a specific version of the DLL and leave the other DLL's with the same name as is.