# SSIS Custom Control Task Debugging UI in BIDS and VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssis, custom-component, bids

I've created a SSIS Custom Task in C# and I'm currently developing the UI.  I was wondering if there is a better way of debugging the UI instead of compiling the project, copying the DLL's into the appropriate DTS folder and then opening the test Package within BIDS and then attaching the process to Visual Studio.  This part I'm not bothered about but once you've tested the UI and made changes to UI within Visual Studio.  I've got to recomplile the DLL's and then repeat the entire process.  I've got to close BIDS and VS because they don't release the DLL's before I have to start the entire process over again.  Does anyone have any tips to speed up this process.  It's just so frustrating having to do this everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would add this.  The best way I've found of debugging SSIS components is to:

In the Project Properties under build set the OUTPUT path to the correct SQL Server DTS sub folder and then in Build under the Post Build events put:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil" -u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Tasks\$(TargetFileName)"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil" /if "$(TargetPath)"

Uninstall the assembly using the gac and then resinstall it.  The reason I'm uninstalling it is because I was having a lot of trouble with BIDS not referencing the newly inserted DLL.  Even restarting my computer it kept referring to the older DLL.  I guess is that it had cached it.  I'm also using this for developing components for BIDS 2012.  I am aware that you don't have to sign or register components with the gac for BIDS 2012 but BIDS was having problems referring to the newly created dll's.  By doing this I dont have to close BIDS everytime or delete and readd the component to the design screen.

You would think there was a simpler version.

Comment: $(TargetFileName) does not work here because you need the display name. See the accepted answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431412/i-can-install-via-gacutil-but-not-uninstall-the-same-dll.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that's the only way Microsoft has devised. If you are repeating this process over and over again, I would suggest creating a batch file for all the operations so that instead of doing 5 steps over and over again you just fire the batch file and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple.  You would think that they would come up with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the blogpost by Matthew Roche [here](http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2008/05/deploying-and-testing-custom-ssis.html). Its quite informative and gives you a better way of doing things.